# Sqlite3 Database Interfacing with AM1808 insert failed silently no error

Tags: sqlite, arm, embedded-linux

I am using sqlite3 Database for the database management for my AM1808 ARM9 based microprocessor.
I am using EMbedded Linux (V10.10 Lucid) and Gcc compiler for ARM.

My scenario is as following,

I have GSM moduled interfaced on UART. I am continuously synchronize my data with the server in background.

I am also accessing SQLIte database for other processes like read,write,view etc..

I have a single database connection.

I have simultaneous access to the Sqlite3.For the Multihandling sqlite3 with a single connection i have used Mutexs for the database lock. I have also used SQLITE3_BUSY flag for checking and all that.

Still i am missing my inserted record in the database, means database is not giving any error for the inserting record to the database.

So i can find that problem.I stuck here and i can not further proceed.
Please guide me. If you need than please tell me i will provide my code snippet.

Comment: You should probably append the code showing the insert routine and error trapping.

Comment: here is my code where i am trying to wait for the Sqlite if it is in Busy state,*
    do
    {
 rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2( ct->db_con, query,-1,&ppStmt,NULL);
 if(SQLITE_BUSY == rc)
 {
     usleep(500000);
     cntr--;
 }
 else if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
 {
     sqlite3_finalize(ppStmt);
     return 1;
 }
 else
 {  if(SQLITE_OK != sqlite3_step(ppStmt)){
       stmt execution if it is failed then try here for 5             times then break from the loop and every time try with          the sqlite3_reset()}else{succes}
 }
    }*